# Call the method every 20 seconds for multiple times then for every minute

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have five tabs on my page.

If I am on Tab5 then I want that the callAutoRefresh function gets called multiple times for 20 seconds followed by auto-refresh every min till the user is on the tab.

If a user leaves the tab then the callAutoRefresh function should stop execution. And then we should start over if we come back to tab5.

```
const initialInterval = setInterval(function() {
  intervalCount++;
  if (intervalCount < 3) {
    callAutoRefresh(id);
  } else {
    const minuteLongInterval = setInterval(function() {
      if (localStorage.getItem("container") == "MyContainer") {
        callAutoRefresh(id);
      } else {
        clearInterval(minuteLongInterval);
      }
    }, 60000);
    clearInterval(initialInterval);
  }
}, 20000);
```

I have tried to use the setInterval() function. The problem is It stops executing when the container gets changed but it already has the getAutoRefresh method stacked up in the memory -
**So if I get back to tab5 it starts executing the getAutoRefresh method for the current id. And stacked up methods for the previous IDs as well.**

Appreciate any small help.

Comment: use the chrome.tabs.onActivated event to track when the user switches to or away from your tab. Then, you can use this event to start and stop the interval timer as needed.
I hope this helps! Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Can you attach an event to the tab switch and clear the intervals there? That would be ideal, since the problem you're having is most likely due to the 60 second interval. Another option is to track the ID in your local storage container and don't call `callAutoRefresh` if the ID isn't correct.